# php how to read URL including # and / symbols

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, get

I have a website with a database of part numbers. My manager wants to be able to type:

```
www.site.com/products/part#
```

and have thepage automatically take you to the relevant page.

Right now I have it take the URL and mod-rewrite the page to:

```
www.site.com/search.php?sku=xxxx
```

And a php srcript will $_GET the sku and do the search, problem is, some part numbers have # and / symbols in them, eg:

```
www.site.com/products/VS816UT#ABA
```

I can get around any slashes with mod-rewrite, but the browsers strips the # symbol before the $_GET can see it.

Is there a way around that?

Comment: no way around it.  it's how <a name="ABA"> works on a web page. it's completely and only in the browser.  There may be an advanced javascript way to do it, but the bottom line is, for what you're asking it just doesn't seem worth the effort.

Comment: @TimG: I think you mean `<a id="ABA">` ;)

Comment: @TimG: Look at the source code of [this page](http://fiddle.jshell.net/YkjFF/show/#one). Only `id` works with the hash marks. `name` produces nothing.

Comment: i've never seen someone using ID to scroll in a document.  not suggesting it's bad - just haven't seen it.  it's interesting.  using anchor tags with name does work and has since the early 90's.  :)

Comment: That's odd. I've never had `name` work for me...

Answer (score 3):

Anything past the hash (the `#`) isn't sent to the webserver.

If you want to get around this, why not append the `#ABA` with a slash:

```
www.site.com/products/VS816UT/ABA
```

And use `mod_rewrite` to properly map it to your PHP file.

Answer (score 1):

the # symbol is reserved for anchor tags inside browsers, in accordance with web standards.

Answer (score 0):

There **should** be no trouble doing it, but what you want is a handler for /products/ that gets the trailing part of the url (frameworks like codeigniter are good at that).

You need a single page handler that dispatches based on as much (or as little) of the url as you need.

Unfortunately, at least some browsers strip the **#** and everything after it. I did a test using a  url with a# and monitored what the browser sent with tcpdump and got this:

Url:

```
http://127.0.0.1/onepage/products/zss#www?b=A#B
```

tcpdump o/p:

```
GET /onepage/products/zss
```

Presumably, server-to-server is the only way this can work.